# Linux - Redirection of a shell script into a text file

Tags: linux, shell

I'm new to Linux, and have been trying to solve an assignment but to no avail.

I have a shell script which prints out lines of a text file in a certain manner (a line within every few seconds):

```
    python << END

import time,random
a= open ('/home/ch/pshety/course/fielding_history.txt','r')
flag =False
for i in range(1000):
   b=a.readline()
   if i==402 or flag:
       print(a.readline())
       flag=True
       time.sleep(2)

END

sh th.sh
```

If I run it without trying to redirect it anywhere, I get the output on the terminal. However, when I tried to redirect it into a new text file, it doesn't do anything - the text remains empty:

```
sh th.sh > debug.txt
```

I've tried looking for answers, I've stumbled upon a lot of suggestions including `tee` but nothing helps - the file remains empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Printing on stderr, writing to a file you're reading at the same time. Plenty of possibilities.

Comment: Try `command > debug.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: @Maroun I tried it, but I get an error: Ambiguous output redirect

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: The only thing you're doing wrong is not waiting long enough.  The system is buffering the data, and won't write any data into the file until the buffer is full.  With the 2 second sleeps per line, that's going to take awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time,random
a = open('/home/ch/pshety/course/fielding_history.txt', 'r')

for i in range(1000):
   b = a.readline()
   if i >= 402:
       print(b, flush=True)
       time.sleep(2)
```

Your Python script likely needs to flush the contents of the output buffer before you can see it.

Note: aside from the `sleep()` call, Unix provides other ways of accomplishing this.  I would take a look at `man tail` and read about the `-f` and `-n` switches.

Edit: didn't realize that `tail` has a switch (`-s`) to sleep as well!